# How to return the name of administrator users in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-11, windows-11-v22h2

I need to get the names of all administrator accounts in Powershell, but this command

```
get-ciminstance -class win32_account | select name | where name -eq administrator
```

returns only the account with the name `administrator`, it doesn't recognize other admin users with different names

I have also tried

```
get-ciminstance -class win32_account | select name | where name -eq administrator*
```

but it doesn't return anything when I use the wildcard.

What do I need to change in order to get a list of admin users on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get-ciminstance -class win32_account | select name | where name -match administrator
```

this will return all the users that have the word administrator in them, for example `administrator1` or `administrator-mike` instead of using `*`, you should be using `-match`

a better commandlet would be:

```
Get-LocalGroupmember -name administrators | select name
```

This will list all administrators like this: computername\user where computername is your computer's name and user is an administrator user
for example: `Windows-pc\Admin123`

if you want an output with only usernames without the computer name, then use:

```
net localgroup administrators
```